# Managing (Creating an deleting) a huge amount of temporal files using C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, filesystems

I'm optimizing a intensive disk usage application, that generates a lot of temporary files, but I have to clean up the folders every day, because we have a limited storage. So, I'm wondering what is the best approach to doit. The files are on a network disk, that is accessed via a Virtual Folder on IIS, so they appear as to be part of the site's own folders.

I have an online PDF Editor, using Aspose.PDF for .Net.
While using the application, it generates a lot of temporal files, but only renders the view when all of them are created. So I'm doing the temporary file creation using a Parallel.For sentence, limited to the numbers of processors available on the machine.

Initially this was done sequentially, and considering that for every page it takes about 1~3 seconds depending on page quality (Aspose limitation, can't optimize it), is taking too long to finish. I've managed to parallelize the operation, but still the times are too high.

In the other hand, I have a routine that deletes all files older than 24 hours (86400 seconds) on several directories. First this was done upon each user request (page load), so it was been executed several times on the page lifecycle, deleting just a bunch of files every time. 
All IIS Application Pools are recycled everyday at 00 hours, so now I'm doing it upon Application_Start, but I'm afraid that it will slow down the first user request, because it has to delete about 45 thousand files (Today the application has been used for 7 hours and there are 30 thousand files already). I'm wondering if is a better approach to do the following:

-Delete some old files upon Session_End (say, delete files older than 4 hours)

-Delete the rest, if any, upon Application_End (older than 24hours).

Also, this routines are called by using async tasks, assuming I don't have to wait them to finish.

For the deletion, I'm using System.IO.FileInfo.Delete() on a for cycle.

Temporary files creation process

```
     Parallel.For(0, TotalPages, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, pageCount =>
                 {
                     using (MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream())
                     {
                         var po = new PageObject();
                         var idx = pageCount + 1;
                         PngDevice p = new PngDevice(); // bajamos un poco la resolución
                         p.RenderingOptions.UseNewImagingEngine = true;
                         p.Process(doc.Pages[idx], imageStream);   //  esta instrucción demora cerca de 1 segundo
                                                                   //System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageStream);
                                                                   //ScaleImage(image, 1138, 760, path_base + fileMask + "-" + idx + ".png", out height, out Aratio);
                                                                   //image.Dispose();
                         using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageStream))
                         {
//this scales the image and writes it to a disc
                             ScaleImage(image, 1138, 760, path_base + fileMask + "-" + idx + ".png", out height, out Aratio);
                         }

                         if (idx == 1) { fields = CheckFields(doc, idx, "image" + fileMask + "-" + idx + ".png", fields, Convert.ToDouble(Aratio)); }
                         po.pageNumber = idx;
                         po.pageName = "image" + fileMask + "-" + idx + ".png";
                         po.Height = height;
                         po.Ratio = Aratio;
                         lpages.Add(po);
                     }
                 });
```

File writing

```
protected static void ScaleImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, string path, out string height, out string Aratio)
        {
            var ratio = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
            Aratio = ratio.ToString();
            var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
            var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
            height = newHeight.ToString();
            //var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            using (var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight))
            {
                Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                using (var bmp = new Bitmap(newImage))
                {
                    bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);
                }
            }
            //newImage.Dispose();
        }
```

The Cleanup Process (variable names in spanish)

```
    private static int _segundos = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PeriodoLimpiezaTemp"].ToString());

    public static void LimpiarTemporales(string rutaTemporal = "", string mask = "*", int? segundos = null)
    {
        int time = segundos ?? _segundos;

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                rutaTemporal = string.IsNullOrEmpty(rutaTemporal) ? Path.GetTempPath() : rutaTemporal;
                var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(rutaTemporal);
                var files = dInfo.GetFiles(mask);
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var dif = (DateTime.Now - file.CreationTime);
                    if (dif.TotalSeconds >= time )
                    {
                        try
                        { //Intenta el eliminar los temporales. Si no puede sigue de largo.
                            file.Delete();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            //do nothing. Just in case some file it's been used by another process. I don't care if any file is left here, the next run may delete it.
                        }
                    }
                };
            });
    }
```

Where I want to use it in Global.asax

```
    protected void Session_End()
    {
        int segundos = 14400;
        LimpiarTemporales(segundos);
    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {
        LimpiarTemporales();
    }
```

What's the best approach for creating the temp files?? (Considering that I have to create them before rendering...)

And the best approach for managing the deletion?

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: You can write delete old files ActionFilter on your action method that execute before  action method. So whenever new request initiate it deletes old files.

Comment: It seems that the problem it's not at the algorithms or the way I'm doing it... Yesterday I was chatting with our Infrastructure team, and they told me that the don't have any alerts about server resources (Network, CPU and RAM usage). So the only thing that it could be is the Disk Storage. 
They told me that our storage is a few years old, so the I/O performance isn't the best, but we are upgrading all of our storages withing a few months.
Still, I'll keep trying to optimize, so any suggestion is welcome.